# Why urls order is important in django for different named urls?

Tags: python, django, url

I have two urls in my urls.py file

```
url('to_quotation/$', views.to_quotation, name='to_quotation'),
url('turn_into_quotation/$', views.turn_into_quotation, name='turn_into_quotation'),
```

and i have two view for them in views.py. When i make an ajax call to 'turn_into_quotation' url, 'to_quotation' view works. But if i changed my urls.py as:

```
url('turn_into_quotation/$', views.turn_into_quotation, name='turn_into_quotation'),
url('to_quotation/$', views.to_quotation, name='to_quotation'),
```

it works properly.

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `^` at the beginning of the regex. Change it to:

```
url(r'^to_quotation/$', views.to_quotation, name='to_quotation'),
url(r'^turn_into_quotation/$', views.turn_into_quotation, name='turn_into_quotation'),
```

Without the `^`, `to_quotation/$` matches **to_quotation/** and also turn_in**to_quotation/**. In that case, the order matters, because Django will use the first URL pattern that matches.

If you're using a recent version of Django, you could use `path()` instead, and avoid regex gotchas.

```
path('to_quotation/', views.to_quotation, name='to_quotation'),
path('turn_into_quotation/', views.turn_into_quotation, name='turn_into_quotation'),
```

Answer (score 0):

@Alasdair's answer is amazing~ I'd like to attach more infomations:

Django use `regex`-like syntax to match it and split `url`'s argument:

```
^to-quotation/<id: int>/$`
```

It will: 1. try to match the url, 2. try to split its argument from `url`, and here it split `int`-value to `id`.

So it is easy to know, in the url's settings, it is important to hold each sub-`url` cannot match another.

Comment: You would either use a regex, e.g. `re_path(r'^to-quotation/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/', ...)` or `path('to-quotation/<id:int>/', ...)`. Your example `^to-quotation/<id: int>/$` is a mixture of the two styles which would cause problems.